# How to fix "not key value coding-compliant" exception when using RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm building an app that talks to an existing REST API. That API was built using a framework called Jackson, I believe, and I thought that I might use RestKit to handle the object creation of objects used by the API. However, I've run into a problem, Jackson likes to send and get JSON that contains structures like this: {"@id": 1, "id": 4} but RestKit chokes on "@id" with a "not key value coding-compliant for the key" exception.

Changing the existing API is going to be an uphill struggle, but I'm wondering if I can shim some sort of conversion that replaces "@id" with a legal key, like "AT__id" on incoming JSON and does the opposite conversion on outgoing JSON. My problem is that I'm new to RestKit and don't know where to begin. I'm contemplating tracing code to see where I might modify the code, but is anyone familiar enough with how it is structured to offer suggestions for where to begin and save me the effort?

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the plug-in parser is the place to try this, has anyone used that and can point to some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that "@id" is a Jackson convention, not a requirement. We tested by changing it to something that conforms to the lowercase/ascii rule and it worked out perfectly. We'll change it for the next server update. This doesn't answer the question, but does solve the immediate problem.